# Implementing range from_to with step

Tags: c++, algorithm

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> Range(int from, int to, int step = 1) {
    std::vector<int> range;

    if (step > 0) {
        for(int i = from; i < to; i += step) {
            range.push_back(i);
        }
    } else if (step < 0) {
        for(int i = from; i > to; i += step) {
            range.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    return range;
}
```

I don't like code duplication in my implementation, because I have two almost identical blocks.
Is it possible to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`signum`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4609795/658087) function returns -1, 0, 1 if the argument is negative, zero, or positive.

```
int original_diff = signum(to-from);
```

When `signum(to-current)` is *different*, we know the relationship changed, regardless of which direction you were going.

```
if (original_diff == 0) return;  //do nothing
for (int current= from;  signum(to-current) != original_diff;  current += step)
```

will do what you want.

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work for this Range(2, 5, 1) or Range(5, 2, -1)

Comment: original is sgn(5-2) = +1.  current=2; current=3 same. current=4 same.  current=5 gives sgn(5-5)=0 which != +1 and the loop stops.  The count-down example works similarly, with the original sgn(2-5)=-1 eventually becoming sgn(2-2)=0 which stops.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Sorry, I used the [proper math name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) as did others in comments and answers, but didn't notice that there was no function in the standard library.  I've added a link to my post.

Answer (score 5):

I think the easiest way to solve this is to first calculate how many steps it takes to go from `from` to `to`, and then just build an array of that many elements. That also has the advantage that you can reserve the right amount of elements in the vector up front. You also have to make sure that `step` has the correct sign.

```
if (from <= to != step > 0)
    step = -step;

size_t distance = std::abs(to - from);
size_t stepsize = std::abs(step);
size_t nsteps = (distance + stepsize - 1) / stepsize;

std::vector<int> range;
range.reserve(nsteps);

for (size_t i = 0; i < nsteps; ++i)
    range.push_back(from + i * step);
```

You also might want to add some check that `step` is not zero.

Comment: looks like your solution doesnt work for those tests:

std::vector<int> expected{-9, -4, 1, 6};
REQUIRE(expected == Range(-9, 10, 5));

std::vector<int> expected{7};
REQUIRE(expected == Range(7, 6, -3));

REQUIRE(Range(3, 7, -1).empty());

Comment: @IvanPetrushenko I forgot to compensate for step sizes larger than 1. I updated my answer.

Comment: @BlameTheBits `auto rq = std::div(to - from, step); size_t nsteps = rq.quot + !!rq.rem`? It's all ugly at this point :)

Comment: Yeah, it really is :D With your descriptive variables it is probably the most clear implementation.

Comment: `to - from` might overflow...

Answer (score 3):

The only difference is the `</>` which swaps on multiplication by a negative factor:
`x < y <=> -x > -y`. An ugly use would be:

```
    for (int i = from; signum(step)*i < signum(step)*to; i += step) {
    for (int i = from; signum(i - to) == signum(step); i += step) {
    for (int i = from; (i - to)*signum(step) < 0; i += step) {
    for (int i = from; (i - to)*step < 0; i += step) {
```

The last choice might seem best, but suffers integer overflow for huge values.

In fact the code duplication seems fine.