# cleaner for loop that accommodates direction

Tags: c++

I have a for loop where I either increment or decrement the value of `i` by 1 each iteration. If `start` is greater than `end` I have to decrement `i` and if `end` is greater than `start` I have to increment `i`

I had written the for loop like so below, in order to keep it always starting at `i = start` and ending at `i = end`

However, with the pattern, I realize that I cannot include the iteration where `i = end`, which with a normal for loop, I could have done with `<=` or `>=` respectively.

What's the cleanest way to write this code?

```
void foo(const int & start, const int & end)
{
   if (start == end) return;

   int iterChange(1);
   if (start > end) iterChange = -1; // if start value is greater, we move in reverse

   for (int i = start; i != end; i = i + iterChange)
   {
        // do something with i
   }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Comment: this has been asked before.  See my answer at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/260416/implementing-range-from-to-with-step/260438#260438

Answer (score 4):

I'm not much of a C++ programmer, I usually just write in C, but this is what I'd do:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>

void foo(int start, int end)
{
    for (int i = std::min(start, end);  i < std::max(start, end);  ++i) {
        std::printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}

int main()
{
    foo( 0,  5);
    foo(-2,  6);
    foo( 8, -7);
}
```

Outputs:

```
0
1
2
3
4
-2
-1
0
1
2
3
4
5
-7
-6
-5
-4
-3
-2
-1
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Basically, the trick is just to always start at the lower bound, and go to the higher bound. With this trick, you don't have to do anything special to avoid cases where `start == end`. And, if you want the loop to be inclusive on both bounds, make the `i <` a `i <=`.

Comment: If the arguments are ass-backwards, OP's solution will enumerate from largest to smallest index. Your solution iterates always in increasing order.

Comment: @coderodde sure, that makes sense to me. If that's really a requirement, then I guess your solution is the way to go, but I didn't really get that as a critical part of the existing code. The inner comment just says to "do something with `i`".

Comment: start -> end direction matters in my case so this solution doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

**Advice 1**

You don't need to pass the parameters via references.

**Advice 2**

For `iterChange`, you can use the `?:` operator.

**Advice 3**

You can write `i += iterChange` instead of `i = i + iterChange`.

**Advice 4**

I would rename `iterChange` to `iterDelta`.

**Advice 5**

You don't really need `if (start == end) return;`

**Summa summarum**

All in all, I thought about the following implementation:

```
void foo(const int start, const int end)
{
    int iterDelta = start > end ? -1 : 1;

    for (int i = start; i != end; i += iterDelta)
    {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.